# How to configure nginx to serve static files to be accessible from root path

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a folder:
/var/www/html/static/fav

that contains files that must be accessible from root path. For example if there is a file:
android-chrome-512x512.png
under that path then:
example.com/android-chrome-512x512.png  should be accessible.

In addition to that

example.com/fav/android-chrome-512x512.png  should also be accessible which is done by adding below rule in nginx conf:

```
location ~* ^/(css|fav|img|js) {
$remote_addr;
    root /var/www/html/static;
    expires 7d;
  }
```

what else I need to change in nginx conf to achieve my goal?

Note that there are files with extensions png, svg, xml  and webmanifest in fav folder . I want all files in fav folder to be accessible.

Comment: You need `root /var/www/html/static/fav;` placed inside a `location` that processes the URI (for example `location /`).

Comment: location / is being used for proxy another app.

Comment: It was only an example. You need to define a location that uniquely identifies the URIs for files in the “fav” folder.

Comment: How? can u answer the question?